# Возможно ли экспортировать один объект из Blender?

Tags: blender

Нужно экспортировать отдельно взятый объект, не удаляя при этом другие объекты из проекта.

Comment: Вы можете просто скопировать этот объект, создать новый файл(сцену, проект), и вставить в него ваш объект

Comment: Да, действенный способ. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Во время выбора директории для экспорта, выберите в панели слева "Selection only"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Месторасположение кнопки меняется в зависимости от скрипта экспорта, и поскольку вы не указали какой формат вас интересует, я привел в качестве примера obj

Comment: У меня по-другому всё это дело отображается. Полагаю, из-за более старой версии, а может это другая тема на скрине, но, главное, работает этот способ, как и способ копирования и вставки, который подсказал пользователь "Gin Tasan". А можете подсказать, какая между этими способами разница?